# Properties of divisors when moving from char 0 to char p.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, positive-characteristic

Consider a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $X$ has models over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ and $X_p=X_{\mathbb{Z}[1/N]}\times \text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is also a smooth projective variety.

Now let $L$ be a line bundle over $X_{\mathbb{Z}[1/N]}$ and $L_\mathbb{C}$ and $L_p$ be the corresponding line bundle over $X=X_{\mathbb{Z}[1/N]}\times\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ and $X_p$ respectively.

How do the properties of $L_\mathbb{C}$ (ample, nef, big, effective) relate to the properties of $L_p$?

For example, if $L_\mathbb{C}$ is nef does this imply that $L_p$ is nef?

Any references or starting points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to migrate this to mathoverflow.